# add bookmark in Firefox without any dialog box

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarks

Using JavaScript, is it possible to add a bookmark in Firefox directly, without opening any dialog box? That is, I want the user clic on a link and that the bookmark is automatically created, without the need to any further step.

Comment: no way in zillion years that would be allowed

Comment: Even if someone found a way to do it in version X, version X+1 would have a bugfix for it. So it's a fundamental no.

Comment: Even if the answer is `NO`, why the question is downvoted? He is just asking something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, no. It would be a horrible breach of security.

Could be a different story in the context of a [**Firefox Extension**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions), but I assume you are asking for a normal web page.

Answer (score 1):

If it was possible, any possible website would be able to create any kind bookmark, without the user even noticing.

As a user, I certainly hope this is not possible ^^

*(And, as a developper, I don't think it is)*